# Why are my load times extremely long?

Tags: starcraft-2, technical-issues

I've been getting a really long load times on the single player campaign. Longer than 5 minutes at times. My rig is pretty decent; I can play the game at ultra without bad framerates. Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: I had some bad windows update that wrecked the MBR. Wasn't able to fix, and had to reinstall Win7. There could have been spyware or viruses present but avast didn't find any. Since the reinstall everything has worked fine.

Comment: Is your graphics driver up-to-date? It's a long shot, but I experienced a similar problem in Bad Company 2 with my Radeon HD 5870 until I updated Catalyst (the problem was mentioned in the release notes).

Answer (score 3):

Load time is generally affected mostly by I/O and not by any other specs.  Even if you can run the game on Ultra with no difficulty, if you have a slow hard drive, low space, high fragmentation, or are using other programs while playing that are reading or writing from the hard drive, these can all negatively impact your load times.

To fix each of these:
Low space can be fixed by uninstalling programs you never or rarely use, or by moving files to a different drive.  I keep all my installs on one drive, and all my data on other drives so it doesn't interfere with load times.

High fragmentation can be fixed by running a defragmentation tool.  Any reasonable operating system will be able to do this for you.

Obviously you should also close any other I/O intensive programs while playing.  Torrenting, in particular, will devastate your load times.

Answer (score 2):

IO-bound software is almost always the problem, in my experience.  Check for:

- Torrents
- Anti-virus
- Background-defragger
- Steam downloading updates, or anything else that could be downloading
- Network shares that other people are reading from

Other problems might be a possibly failing hard-drive, or [using up too much memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29).  Fragmentation is rarely a problem, despite popular opinion.